# Texas Hold'em and pocket ace

Tags: texas-hold-em

What are the overall chances that a single pocket ace in texas hold'em will be the winning hand, regardless of the other card?

Comment: But there is another card or the hand will be dead.  This question cannot be answered.  VTC

Answer (score 1):

You can use this page as a [quick reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability_%28Texas_hold_%27em%29#Starting_hands_heads_up) but the exact odds are 0.00452 or 220 : 1.

Comment: Those are the odds of receiving aces (or any specific pair), which is just 6 combinations {AcAd,AcAh,AcAs,AdAh,AdAs,AhAs} divided by 1,326 possible (52 choose 2). Depending on how you read the question, the odds of winning with AA against one random hand are 85.204% and with Ax against one random hand are 61.14%.